# Taking the logarithm of a formal power series definition

Tags: combinatorics, formal-power-series

I came across with the logarithm of a formal power series in a paper i am reading, but i have not found what is the definition of this 'operator(?)'. Can someone please let me know the definition and if the log obeys the same rules as in calculus?

I must add that I have this particular example:

[image]

Based on Mike answer, why is that in the second equality there is not a $(-1)^{k-1}$ term in the inner summation?

I'll really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Take the Taylor series of $\log x$, and plug in your series as $x$. Yes, it satisfies some of the same properties (assuming everything is commutative). Like $\log uv=\log u +\log v$, provided $\log u$, $\log v$ are defined,  and $\exp \log u=u$.

Comment: okay. So that is the definition of the log operator right?

Comment: Yes. Note that it is not everywhere defined.

Comment: To your edit: $\log\left(1\over 1-y\right)=-\log(1-y)=-\sum (-1)^{n-1}(-y)^n/n=\sum y^n/n$. Apply that to $y=x^{s(a)}$.

Comment: thanks @MikeEarnest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $F(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0} f_nx^n$ is a formal power series, and if $G(x)=\sum_{\color{blue}{n\ge 1}}g_nx^n$ is a power series for which $G(0)=0$, then the composite power series $(F\circ G)(x)$ is defined as
$$
(F\circ G)(x)= f_0+f_1\cdot G(x)+f_2 [G(x)]^2+f_3[G_3(x)]^3+\dots
$$
The condition $G(0)=0$ is necessary for this to be a well-defined power series.

You can apply this with $F(x)=\log(1+x)=\sum_{n\ge 1} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}n$ to get a power series representation for $\log(1+G(x))$, which gives meaning to take the $\log$ of $1+G(x)$. This will still satisfy the properties of $\log$, like $\log[(1+G)(1+H)]=\log(1+G)+\log(1+H)$.

Comment: i have a question, shouldn't it be log(1+x) = summation $(-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^n}{n} $?

Comment: @Mangostino Yes, thank you.

Comment: Maybe i must add my concrete example in order to get better the idea. I'm updating my question